# Find record that contains value

Tags: mysql

I have a value from Table1.

Next, I want to see if the primary key of Table2 is part of Table1.value.

Examples:

```
Table1.value = "invoice 2016-213";
```

or like:

```
Table1.value = "518951932159 INVOICENR 54504247213";

Table2.primaryKey = "213";
```

So, I try to do a search on '213' in Table1.value.

This can't be the right way to go, since it isn't working:

```
select * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.primaryKey LIKE ('%Table1.value%')";
```

Anyone an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the inverse

```
select * FROM Table2 
WHERE Table1.value LIKE concat( '%', Table2.primaryKey, '%')  
or  Table1.value LIKE concat( Table2.primaryKey, '%')  
or  Table1.value LIKE concat( '%', Table2.primaryKey)
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge! You nailed it. It is working here. Super cool!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Table2 a
where primaryKey in (
  select distinct value
  from Table1
  where value like concat('%', a.primaryKey, '%')
)
```